# Calculating feature size of HOG

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have confusion in understanding the feature size which is extracted from `extractHOGFeatures(I,varargin)` a function from matlab. My image size `120x54` and when I used this function with default values of this function, `Cellsize [8 8]`, `Block size [2 2]`, `NumBin=9`. The size of output features using this function is `1980x1`. But, I heard there is a simple formula to calculate the size of features `Cellsize*Numbin` which is `8*8*9=576`. So, I am confused that might be I am getting wrong number of feature. Can anyone tell me the extract formula is there any so I can validate that I am getting correct number of features?

Comment: Maybe one should add that [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html) is part of the Computer Vision toolbox which may not be so commonly used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement @Dima's answer, the docs on [extractHOGFeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html#inputarg_BlockOverlap) give the formula to calculate the HOG features length:

```
N = prod([BlocksPerImage, BlockSize, NumBins])
```

where

```
 BlocksPerImage = floor((size(I)./CellSize - BlockSize)./(BlockSize - BlockOverlap) + 1)
```

and

```
 BlockOverlap = ceil(BlockSize/2)
```

Comment: Here is the link of that paper. You can see in description of Fig 2 he explained the method of calculating features. 
[Paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-69162-4_62)

Comment: Also, I want to know that, If I have image `I` of size `120x50` and I apply HOG to extract features. and in second way I divide the image into 4 equal parts and apply HOG on each part and then concatenate the features of all four block. So, these concatenated features will have same information as the features extracted from whole image?

Comment: Thanks for the paper! And yes I believe it should be the same for smaller images making up one big image.

Comment: Did you say that paper? what do you think the formula presented in MATLAB is correct or the one presented in the paper?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's clarify terminology.  When you compute a HOG feature vector from an image, the image is divided into possibly overlapping blocks, each block is divided into cells, and then a histogram of orientations is computed for each cell.

In your case the block size is 2x2 cells. So the number of feature elements for each block is `BlockSize * NumBin`, which is 2x2x9. The number of blocks in the image depends on the image size and on the `BlockOverlap` parameter.

Comment: can you please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773298/confusion-in-different-hog-codes)